# Ubuntu 16.04 - PHP 7.1.11 to 7.1.3

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, php, versions, php7

How can I upgrade my **PHP version** from PHP **7.1.11** to **7.1.3** on my **Ubuntu 16.04** server? I've tried the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php7.1
```

But them I'm getting the following response:

```
php7.1 is already the newest version (7.1.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
```

Also tried to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1.3
```

But then I am getting this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.1.3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1.3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1.3'
```

How can I upgrade minor version?

Comment: You are not upgrading, in fact, you are degrading your php version.

Comment: Take look at this accepted answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111922/upgrade-to-the-latest-php-version-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 4):

Since official repo comes with 7.0 version, repo from [ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) has 7.1

Add the repository :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Update :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install 7.1:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-common
```

if needed you can remove old packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.0 php7.0-common
```

Comment: This only installed 7.1.25 for me